# How to open an Expo React Native project in Xcode in order to create a build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I have an expo react native app's project and xcode simply denies to open it. I looked up for the solutions on internet but it says it can be done through podfile but there is no such file or ios folder in an expo react native project. How can I open it in xcode

Comment: You don't need that with Expo, follow the steps mentioned here https://pagepro.co/blog/publishing-expo-react-native-app-to-ios-and-android/

Comment: a youtube video How to publish Expo React Native App to Apple App Store (step-by-step tutorial) https://youtu.be/LE4Mgkrf7Sk. They have a Google Play video too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you dont have the ios and android folders then it sounds you have a managed work flow expo project. This is a react native project where all the code you write is pure javascript and all of the native side code is managed by expo. If this is what you want then you just need to use [expo build tools](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/ios-builds/). If you must build with xcode then [eject your project](https://docs.expo.dev/expokit/eject/) and open the ios folder in xcode and build from there